# What is a relation (finitely related module)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_module#Finitely_presented.2C_finitely_related.2C_and_coherent_modules

I've understood the first part of the definition. Then, "M is isomorphic to F/ker(φ)" follows (trivially) from the first isomorphism theorem.

But when they say "taking a free module and introducing finitely many relations within F", what do they mean by relations?

Comment: You can think of a relation as an equation involving the generators of $F$, just as you would for a [group](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/group/genrel.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can present a module $M$ over a ring as follows - take a free module $F$. Its generators are called "the generators". Now form the quotient $M=F/H$ by a submodule $H$ of $F$. The generators of $H$ are called "the relations". We have the exact sequence
$$
F\rightarrow H \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0.
$$

Comment: Regarding the exact sequence:

all of $M$ must map to 0, so $H$ must map to all of $M$. This is clear. But we also require that $im(F\rightarrow H)=ker(H \rightarrow M)$. Does this mean that $F\rightarrow H$ just maps the elements of $F$ that are in $H$ to themselves?